# Columns with group by + count using left join for consult in SQL or Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

First, i show my tables and my query:

```
Tbl_type: id, description (1,Type A)-(2,Type B)-(3,Type C)

Tbl_operation: id, client, type, import (1,1,1,100.00)-(2,1,1,75.00)-(3,1,1,44.00)-(4,1,2,90.00)-(5,1,2,11.00)
```

When i exe this query :

```
SELECT Operation.Client, Type.description AS Type, Count(Operation.Id) AS Nr
FROM Tipo LEFT JOIN
     Operation
     ON Type.Id = Operation.type
GROUP BY Type.description, Operation.Client;
```

i got like output:

```
Client,Type,Nr (1,Type A,3)-(1,Type B,2)
```

but, i want to obtained this:

```
Client,Type,Nr (1,Type A ,3)-(1,Type B,2)-(1,Type C,0)
```

Also, I'd had a second client (id=2)

Tbl_operation:  `id, client, type, import (1,1,1,100.00)-(2,1,1,75.00)-(3,1,1,44.00)-(4,1,2,90.00)-(5,1,2,11.00)-(6,2,3,66.00)`

Then, the consult should do this too:

```
Client,Type,Nr (1,Type A,3)-(1,Type B,2)-(1,Type C,0)-(2,Type A,0)-(2,Type B,0)-
(2,Type C,1)
```

This is possible? or i have to do a subselect?. I have tried to use full outer join but it doesnt work because it shows only registered rows.